# Flask server side validation for format of post request

Tags: python, flask

I have an HTML form with an input for a US dollar value.

```
<tr>
                                        <form action="/save_report/" method="POST">
                                        <td>{{event.event_name}}</td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name='id' id="e_name" value="{{event.event_ID}}">
                                        <td>{{event.office}}<br></td>
                                        <td>{{event.event_city}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                        {% for r in event.reps %}
                                        <li>{{r.date_worked.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}} By {{r.rep}}</li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{event.items}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                          <label for="total">Total bill for event</label><br>
                                          <input type="number" min=0 step=".01" id="total" value="" name="total" placeholder="50.00" required><br>
                                          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{event.event_ID}}">
                                          <input type="hidden" name="office" value="{{event.office}}">
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Save</button>
                                        </td>
                                        </form>
                                      </tr>
```

this only works in some browsers, and I do not care for the little arrows on the numbers input.

I could check with JS but if user has it turned off it still will not solve the problem.

I would like to post the data to server and make sure the string in the post request is formatted as 12.34 and if not return an error to HTML.

Here is current server side:

```
@app.route('/save_report/',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def save_report():
    role = session.get('role')
    name = session.get('name')
    id = session.get('id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        total=request.form['total']
        event=request.form['id']
        office=request.form['office']

        print(total,event,office)

    return redirect(url_for('reports'))
```

My thought is some sort of if statement like this

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    total=request.form['total']
    event=request.form['id']
    office=request.form['office']

    # Need to validate format here?
    if total != "11.11":
        return redirect(url_for('reports' error=error))
    else:
    print(total,event,office)

return redirect(url_for('reports'))
```

However I am lost on how to check the format of a string. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly what you are looking for is how to check if `total` is float value. You could simply check it with `re` module.

```py
@app.route('/save_report/',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def save_report():
    role = session.get('role')
    name = session.get('name')
    id = session.get('id')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        total=request.form['total']
        event=request.form['id']
        office=request.form['office']

        if re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", total) is None:
            return redirect(url_for('error_page'))
    return redirect(url_for('reports'))
```

Other than regex you could just simply check like this also.

```
try:
    f_total = float(total)
except ValueError:
    return redirect(url_for('error_page'))
```

If you only want accept two digit float value with two digit decimals you could use this regex `re.match("^\d{2}\.\d{2}$", total)`

Comment: I think I might run into a problem with this if the user enters a whole number correct? for example 50 rather than 50.00?